# How can I fetch data only from specific date using firestore?

Tags: date, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to put all of the documents from a collection in a list using firestore, I want documents that were only uploaded in a certain year.

There is a field in all of the documents called "dateAdded", which stores the date formatted in 'dd-MM-yyyy'.

for testing I only have 3 documents, 2 uploaded in 2020 and 1 in 2019

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot= await Firestore.instance
                      .collection('Deceased')
                      .where("dateAdded",
                      isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:"01-01-"+year )
                       .where("dateAdded",isLessThanOrEqualTo:"31-12-"+year )
                      .getDocuments();
```

I have tried to do it this way, only the first condition works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called `startAt` or `startAfter` and `endAt` or `endBefore` which you can use, to use that you must first orderby the field you want to use query on so, here I am using `startAt` and `endAt` which should give you the result you want which I believe is the record for a whole year

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot= await Firestore.instance
                      .collection('Deceased')
                      .orderBy('dateAdded')
                      .startAt([DateTime(year,1,1,0,0,0)])
                      .endAt([DateTime(year,12,31,23,59,59])(
                      .getDocuments();
```

Comment: The argument type 'DateTime' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'. 
This is the error I get. Also as I mentioned I have changed the format of the date, could that be an issue?

Comment: have you not saved datetime as timestamp in firestore? If not that this will not work.

Comment: Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
              firestore.collection("Deceased").add({
               
                "dateAdded" : format.format(DateTime.now()) ,
               
              });

I am adding the field into the collection using this method.

Comment: If you are in development phase instead of keeping dateTime as string use this to save date time as timestamp `Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance; firestore.collection("Deceased").add({ "dateAdded" : DateTime.now() , });` however if you already have large data set and updating is a tedious task, may be using `[format.format(DateTime(year,1,1,0,0,0))]` in place of `[DateTime(year,1,1,0,0,0)]` might work too, as string should be ordered properly. Should be done for both startAt and endAt values

Comment: I managed to add a field to store the timestamp and it works just fine, Thanks Alot!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are storing data as a string. I suggest to store the data in seconds like this

```
final dateNow = DateTime.now();
final int seconds = (dateNow.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000);
```

Once you have the data in firebase as second it is super easy to handle it

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot= await Firestore.instance
                      .collection('Deceased')
                      .where("dateAdded",
                      isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:xxxxxxx)
                       .where("dateAdded",isLessThanOrEqualTo:yyyyyy )
                      .getDocuments();
```

xxxxxxx and yyyyyy need to be an int. Look at https://www.epochconverter.com to understand how epoch time work

As an example, if you want to capture all record in 2019 you should first determine the epoch time for the 1st of Jan 2019 and then the time in second for the 31st of Dec 2019. If you use the website you will get the following

- 1st Jan 2019 = 1546300800
- 31st Dec 2019 = 1577836799

[image]
So your code should look like this

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot= await Firestore.instance
                      .collection('Deceased')
                      .where("dateAdded",
                      isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1546300800)
                       .where("dateAdded",isLessThanOrEqualTo: 1577836799 )
                      .getDocuments();
```

Comment: I need to make a method that would fetch data from any year based on the value of the 'year' variable, how would that work?

Comment: I have added an example with real numbers